# Notifications disabled on file system in Safari?

Tags: javascript, web-notifications

When in Safari and calling requestNotification the prompt never appears.

Code:

```
Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
    console.log(permission); // always denied

    if (permission === "granted") {
        // never hits this block
    }

});
```

Testing on Mac OSX

More info on [Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

**Update:**
It appears to work correctly when running on localhost but not file system, `file://` vs `http://localhost/`

Comment: It can't work on `file://` because the permission is always associated to a domain.

Comment: But it works in Firefox on the file system